# cannot use pip to install packages in virtual env for Python in VSCODE

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to set up a virtual environment for python in VSCODE, here is my command to create virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

and use this command to activate the virtual env:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

and tried to use pip to install packages in the virtual env but the packages installed in the local python path, I use `which pip`to check whether pip is in the virtual env and it's actually in the virtual env:

```
/xxxxxx/venv/bin/pip
```

but when I use this command to install packages:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

got the warning message:

```
Target directory/xxxxxxxxx (the local python route) already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement
```

and the installed packages are not shown in my virtual env, can you please help me to figure it out? Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the content of the *requirements.txt* file?

Comment: @OldBoy it's just some basic packages, like django

Comment: We need more information. There is not enough in your question to guess what is wrong. I have used virtual environments in Python many times and never seen a problem with installing packages inside the venv.